# How to show that $E_i \to E_j \to E=E_i \to E$ for $i<j$

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

The proof that I am trying to detail is that of Theorem 6.23 of the Book of Abelian Categories by Peter Freyd. The statement is as follows.

*Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a Grothendieck category, $I$ and ordered set, and $\{f_{kj}:E_k\to E_j \}_{k<j}$ a family of monomorphism such that for $k<j<l$, $E_k \to E_j \to E_l =E_k \to E_l$. Then there exits an object $E \in \mathcal{B}$ and a family of monomorphism $\{g_j:E_j \to E\}$ such that for $k<j$, $$E_k \to E_j \to E=E_k \to E$$ *

Sketch of proof:
Let $S=\sum \limits_{j\in J} E_j$ be the sum of family $\{E_j\}_{j \in J}$ with canonical inyections $i_j:E_j \to S$. For fix each $j \in J$, by the  universal propiety of $S=\sum \limits_{j\in J}  E_j$ apliedd to family  $E_j=\{i_j \circ f_{kj}:E_k \to S       \}_{k<j}  \cup \{i_k: E_k \to S \}_{j \leq k} $, exist  unique morfism $h_j:S \to S$ such that

> for $k<j$, the triangle
>
> [image] commutes

and

> for $j\leq k$ the triangle
>
> [image]
>   commutes

Of this construction its follows the nexts statement:

(a)For each $k,j \in J$, el morfismo $h_j \circ i_k:E_k \to E_j$ is a monomorphism.

(b) if $j^\prime<j$, then  triangle

[image] 
        is conmutative.

(c) The family $\bigcup \ker(h_j)$ is a ascendent chain with the inclusion of subobjets.

take an epimorphism $h:S\to E$ such that $\ker(h)=\bigcup_k\ker(h_k)$ (it can be for example the cokernel of the subobject $\bigcup_k\ker(h_k)$). For each $j$, let $g_j=h\circ i_j:E_j\to E$. The family formed by the $g_j$ will be the required family. To verify that you must prove that

1. the $g_j=h \circ i_j$ are monomorphism. Its follow of items (a),(b) and (c).
2. if $k<j$, then the triangle

[image]
conmuta.

My question is how show the item 2.  I made is the following:
To prove that the triangle above commutes, by definition of $g_k$ and $g_j$, I must prove that the diagram

[image]

commutes

Now, by definition of $h_j$ and inequality $k<j$, the quadrilateral of the diagram

[image]
commutes. Then, to check the conmutative of all the triangle, must show the conmutative of upper triangle. It is $h \circ h_j=h$. My problem is : How show this?

Comment: You can check $h\circ h_j = h$ by composing with all the inclusions $E_k\to S$ because $S$ is their sum

Comment: ¿ check $h \circ h_j \circ i_k=h \circ i_k, \forall k \in J$ and so, by uniquesess, $h \circ h_j=h$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting

Comment: ok. for $j\leq k$, by definition of $h_j$, $h \circ h_j \circ i_k=h \circ i_k$. For $k<j$, i must also the same. Now, if $k<j$,then, by definition of $h_j$, $h \circ h_j \circ i_k=h \circ i_j \circ f_{kj}$. But, how did I get this is equal to $h \circ i_k$.

Comment: $i_k - i_j\circ f_{kj} $ lands in $\ker(h_j)$ by definition, so it lands in $\ker(h)$ by construction.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I obteniedt the equality. Thank you very much.